# Paypal api oauth

Tags: angularjs, curl, paypal, oauth

The documentation says to obtain `oauth` token use the following :

> curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
>     -H "Accept: application/json" \
>     -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
>     -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
>     -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

How to send `-u` and `-d` parameters using `angular js`

```
    var senddata = {
        clientId:"Ac8T1BCmIxgxbS5O_ztwejxvNW8Cbr0y1724_2cd8bGl68axHyw_nEdcOBli",
        secret:"EAwgXhALV78LnphCPf-R3zs1Dx3nkcIOMc4TftSLh9q5EpgyqdeE19El9Oh0",
        grant_type:"client_credentials"
    };
```

Tried passing `senddata` in `http.post`(`url,senddata`)

But I am getting

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
```

Comment: you'll have to include the authentication information in the header of the HTTP request. senddata seems to add the data to the payload. Found a nice post on http headers and angualar js under http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/authentication-to-a-restful-web-service-in-an-angularjs-web-app

Comment: What should be the name of the authentication header ?

Comment: Check Finn K's answer for the authentication header, and AngularJS' `$http.post` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) for the syntax (headers are in a third parameter).

Comment: don't you get crossed domain error?

Answer (score 5):

I'm making a PayPal API call in the context of an e-Commerce solution I'm developing in Angular-JS. I was able to get an auth_token back from PayPal using the following code. The two gotchas that caught me up for some time were:

1. The ClientId and ClientSecret have to be joined by a colon and base64 encoded (as FinnK says above)
2. When sending the data as an object `data: {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}` I was receiving an error that 'grant_type' is a required parameter. After changing this to a string joined with an equals sign I no longer received this error.

   ```
   var basicAuthString = btoa('CLIENTID:SECRET');
   $http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
       'Authorization': 'Basic ' + basicAuthString,
     },
     data: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
   })
   .success(function(data){
     console.log(data.access_token);
   })
   .error(function(error){
     console.error(error);
   });
   ```

I hope this was helpful for someone stuck trying to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Client id and secret need be sent in an `Authorization` header.

Client id and secret need be concatenated with a `:` separator (e.g. `client:secret`), and then encoded in base 64. This is called [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), and what cURL does behind the scene when using the `-u` option.

You can pass custom headers to `$http.post` in a third parameter. See the [method documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post). Example, using `$http` directly (and heavily inspired from the documentation):

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.com',
  headers: {
   'Authorization': "Basic 12Base346456enc0did"
  },
  data: { grant_type: 'client_credentials' }
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```